# React Native - How to get the values of FlatList Items from Parent

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, use-ref

I'm using Flat list which has items rendered. Each item in the flat list is a custom component, has a state that holds an integer value. Below the Flat list, I have a button and on clicking it has to print the values of the state variable in the items. I'm trying with "useRef" array. I'm not able to access the items of the flat list. I'm missing something to handle it.

Here's my code for reference:

```
//Custom Component
export const SelectionOptions = (props: any) => {
    const {
        title = '',
        options = [],
        selected = [],
        allowSingleSelection = true,
    } = props;

    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState(selected);

  
    return (
    <View>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </View>
            )
}


//Parent
const OnBoardingScreen = () => {

    const flatList = createRef<FlatList<any>>();
    const [currentDisplayingPage, setCurrentDisplayingPage] = useState(0);
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);
    const itemEls = useRef(new Array())

    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            value: {
                title: 'Age Group',
                options: [
                    { id: 1, value: { left: 'A', right: '18-30' } },
                    { id: 2, value: { left: 'B', right: '31-45' } },
                    { id: 3, value: { left: 'C', right: '45-64' } },
                    { id: 4, value: { left: 'D', right: '65+' } },
                ],
                singleSelection: true
            }
        },
    ]);

    const renderItem = (item) => {
        return (
            <SelectionOptions
                title={item.value.title}
                options={item.value.options}
                allowSingleSelection={item.value.singleSelection}
                ref={(element) => { itemsEls[item.id] = element; }}
            />
        );
    };

    return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
                
            <FlatList
                scrollEnabled={false}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                horizontal
                pagingEnabled
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={data}
                renderItem={(item) => renderItem(item.item)}
                ref={flatList}
            />
            <Button onPress={() = {
                for item in each itemsEls {
                    console.log(item.current.selectedItems);
                }
            }} title=“Click Me”/>
            />
        </Container >
    );
}


export default OnBoardingScreen;
```

Comment: with `itemsEls[item.id]`did you mean `itemsEls[item.item.id]`?
I suggest you to destructure item in renderItem: `const renderItem = ({ item }) => {...}` avoiding redundant item.item everytime

Comment: @Milore Thanks for the suggestion about destructuring. I updated my code. Can u now you check and tell me the way to handle the refs in flatlist ?

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
    Data = [
        {
            id : 1,
            email : 'abc@gmail.com',
            first_name : 'abc',
        },
        {
          id : 2,
          email : 'xyz@gmail.com',
          first_name : 'xyz',
      },
         {
          id : 3,
          email : 'pqr@gmail.com',
          first_name : 'pqr',
      } ,
        {
          id : 4,
          email : 'mno@gmail.com',
          first_name : 'mno',
      },
         {
          id : 5,
          email : 'rst@gmail.com',
          first_name : 'rst',
      }
    ]
  const renderDataList = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{marginLeft: '10%'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}> {item.email}</Text>
          <Text> {item.first_name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
          }}></View>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView> 
        <FlatList 
            data={Data} 
            renderItem={renderDataList} 
            keyExtractor={item=>{item.id}} 
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```